# Display a file name in PHP (e.g. document.pdf) that is in MySql?

Tags: mysql

how to display a file **name** in PHP (e.g. document.pdf) that is in MySql in a BLOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BLOB`s don't have filenames. They're just a string of bytes. They represent the file contents, not the file itself. So you will have to either create a column and save the filename when the BLOB is inserted (the MIME type is not a bad idea, too), or make one up when you serve it to the user.